# How to prove $Re \int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp(e^{ix})\cos(nx) = \frac{\pi}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

My attempt :
Consider $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos(x)}\cos(\sin(x))\cos(nx)$ , let's represent it like $Re \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}\cos(nx) = Re \sum \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i(k+n)x}}{k!}$. After integration and considering $k = 0$ (other members will disappear after integration) we get : $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Where I go wrong ?

Comment: $\text{Re}(e^{e^{ix}} \cos(nx)) \neq \text{Re}(e^{e^{ix}} e^{inx}) $. If $a,b$ are complex numbers, $\text{Re}(a)\text{Re}(b) = \text{Re}(ab)$ simply does not hold.

Comment: You also made another mistake $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(k+n) x} dx$ is zero unless $k=-n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking, hopefully, a simpler approach [from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#For_continuous_functions)
$$\int\limits_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$
and [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)

$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}\cos(nt)dt=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}\frac{e^{nit}+e^{-nit}}{2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}e^{nit}dt + \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}e^{-nit}dt\right)=\\
\frac{1}{2}\left(-i\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}e^{(n-1)it}(e^{it})'dt -i \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{e^{it}}}{e^{(n+1)it}}(e^{it})'dt\right)=\\
\frac{-i}{2}\left(\color{red}{\int\limits_{|z|=1}e^zz^{n-1}dz}+\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^{n+1}}dz\right)=...$$
using [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) for the part in red
$$...=\frac{-i}{2}\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^{n+1}}dz=
\frac{-i}{2}f^{(n)}(0)\frac{2\pi i}{n!}=f^{(n)}(0)\frac{\pi}{n!}$$
where $f(z)=e^z$, so $f^{(n)}(0)=1$. As a result:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}\cos(nt)dt=\frac{\pi}{n!}$$